# Share content with specific app only with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use UIActivityViewController to share my content but only with some specific applications (Mail, email, Gmail, yahoomail). How can I share my content using mail app apps only. No other app needs to be viewed.

Comment: How did you display Gmail and Yahoo mail apps in UIActivityViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude all the activites but the `UIActivityTypeMail`'s :

```
NSArray *activitiesToExclude = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
```

and pass that array to your controller :

```
myActivityController.excludedActivityTypes = activitiesToExclude;
```

So that you can keep the `UIActivityTypeMail` activity.

Comment: @TejasPatel You are welcome. Please, check the correct answer if it suits your needs ;)